# How many numbers less than $100$ can be expressed as a sum of distinct factorials?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math, factorial

How many numbers less than $100$ can be expressed as a sum of distinct factorials?

Example:

a) $4 = 2! + 2!$

b) $3 = 2! + 1!$

Comment: How is $2!+2!$ sum of *distinct* factorials?

Comment: @kingW3 changed the question!

Comment: Notice that $5! = 120 > 100$, which greatly limits the number of possibilities.  The question in the title is more interesting than the one in the body.

Comment: Since only the first 4 factorials are less than 100, there are $4\cdot5/2=10$ combinations.

Comment: You should not change the question after it has been answered.  Please change the question back to the version in the original title.  If you still need a response to the question in the body, ask a separate question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig done

Comment: @LinuxGeek ; Did you mean $4=0!+1!+2!$ instead of  $4=2!+2!$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma(I)**: For every positive integer $n$ we have: 
$$ 
1! + 2! + ... + (n-1)! < n! 
\ \ 
$$

---

There are 
$ 
\color{Green}{15} = 
\color{Green}{16} 
\color{Red}{-1}   = 
\color{Green}{2^4} 
\color{Red}{-1}$.

$$n= 
\varepsilon_1 (1!) 
+ 
\varepsilon_2 (2!) 
+ 
\varepsilon_3 (3!) 
+ 
\varepsilon_4 (4!) 
; 
$$

where $\varepsilon_i \in \{0,1\}$ for $i=1, 2, 3, 4$.

---

Because for every $\varepsilon_i$ 
we have two choices.
The $\color{Red}{-1}$ appears 
because the case 
$\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_2=\varepsilon_3=\varepsilon_4=0$ 
is not allowed;
as @Professor Vector has been mentioned.

---

---

---

---

**If $0!$ permited to join the sum** then:

---

**Lemma(II)**: For every integer $3 \leq n$ we have: 
$$ 
0! + 1! + 2! + ... + (n-1)! < n! 
\ \ 
$$

---

There are 
$ 
\color{Green}{23} = 
\color{Green}{24} 
\color{Red}{-1}   = 
\color{Green}{3.2^4} 
\color{Red}{-1}$.

$$n= 
\varepsilon_0 (0!) 
+ 
\varepsilon_1 (1!) 
+ 
\varepsilon_2 (2!) 
+ 
\varepsilon_3 (3!) 
+ 
\varepsilon_4 (4!) 
; 
$$

where $\varepsilon_i \in \{0,1\}$ for $i=0, 1, 2, 3, 4$.

---

Because for each of 
$\varepsilon_2, \varepsilon_3, \varepsilon_4$ 
we have two choices;
and we have three coices for choosing 
$\varepsilon_0, \varepsilon_1$;
i.e. 
$(\varepsilon_0, \varepsilon_1)= 
(0,0) 
\ \ \ 
\text{or} 
\ \ \ 
(0,1) 
\ \ \ 
\text{or} 
\ \ \ 
(1,1) 
.
$
[Notice 
that the two pairs 
$(\varepsilon_0, \varepsilon_1)= (0,1)$ 
and 
$(\varepsilon_0, \varepsilon_1)= (1,0)$ 
are the same. 
]
The $\color{Red}{-1}$ appears 
because the case 
$\varepsilon_0=\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_2=\varepsilon_3=\varepsilon_4=0$ 
is not allowed;
as @Professor Vector has been mentioned.

Comment: That would include the empty sum, I don't think that's what the OP had in mind (even though we can't be sure what that is, since title and question don't agree).

Comment: @ProfessorVector I actually did a mistake in the main question! Kindly post the solution of the revised question

Comment: Your lemma is valid for positive integers.

Comment: @Professor Vector ; you are right. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig ; you are right. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Famke Why the $-1$ from the final answer?

Comment: @LinuxGeek ; The $\color{Red}{-1}$ appears 
because the case 
$\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_2=\varepsilon_3=\varepsilon_4=0$ 
is not allowed;  
as "Professor Vector" has been mentioned above. This case gives us $n=0$; which is not natural.